# Printf with strings as arguments

Tags: c, output

Consider the following:

```
char abc[14] = "C Programming"; printf("%s", abc + abc[3] - abc[4]);
```

The output of the above printf statement is "rogramming". I can't seem to figure how this output is obtained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`abc` is an array. When used in expression, in most cases, it converted to pointer to its first element. `abc[3]` is a `char` which is `'r'`. `abc[4]` is `'o'`. `abc[3] - abc[4]` = `'r' - 'o' = 3`. `abc + 3` = `&abc[3]`.
So, the expression `abc + abc[3] - abc[4]` is equivalent to pointer to 3<sup>rd</sup> charater of string `"C Programming"`.

Answer (score 5):

Because chars are a form of integers.

```
    abc + abc[3] - abc[4]
==> abc + 'r' - 'o'
==> abc + 3
```

And thus you print the string abc starting at index 3.

Comment: Sorry bro :( but what you said is not true.

Comment: @GRC Why don't you share your thoughts :)

Comment: The fact that chars have numerical value does not have to do with what he did. @Hacks wrote right answer.

Comment: @GRC He wrote exactly the same thing. I quote: `'r' - 'o' = 3`

Comment: He (@GRC) is talking about pointer arithmetic which is addressed in my answer.

Comment: I thought this was obvious that `abc + 3` is pointer arithmetic. The confusing part was the `abc[4] - abc[3]`. However, his comment **is** confusing. What I said is **true** and maybe *incomplete*.

Comment: @fjardon +1 I see your point, :) pointer arithmetic is what I was thinking about.